# Can't upload my custom plugin because of a Warning: dirname()

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, controller, dirname

I have created a custom wordpress plugin in local. I wanted to upload it on a website but now when I try to activate I get a error.

**This is the error:**

```
Warning: dirname() expects exactly 1 parameter, 2 given in /home/x/x/x/x/x/wp-content/plugins/X-plugin/inc/Base/BaseController.php on line 18

Warning: dirname() expects exactly 1 parameter, 2 given in /home/x/x/x/x/x/wp-content/plugins/X-plugin/inc/Base/BaseController.php on line 19

Warning: dirname() expects exactly 1 parameter, 2 given in /home/x/x/x/x/x/wp-content/plugins/X-plugin/inc/Base/BaseController.php on line 20

Warning: dirname() expects exactly 1 parameter, 2 given in /home/x/x/x/x/x/wp-content/plugins/X-plugin/inc/Base/BaseController.php on line 18

Warning: dirname() expects exactly 1 parameter, 2 given in /home/x/x/x/x/x/wp-content/plugins/X-plugin/inc/Base/BaseController.php on line 19

Warning: dirname() expects exactly 1 parameter, 2 given in /home/x/x/x/x/x/wp-content/plugins/X-plugin/inc/Base/BaseController.php on line 20
```

**My code is:**

```
<?php 
/**
 * @package  XPlugin
 */
namespace Inc\Base;

class BaseController
{
    public $plugin_path;

    public $plugin_url;

    public $plugin;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->plugin_path = plugin_dir_path( dirname( __FILE__, 2 ) );
        $this->plugin_url = plugin_dir_url( dirname( __FILE__, 2 ) );
        $this->plugin = plugin_basename( dirname( __FILE__, 3 ) ) . '/X-plugin.php';
    }
}
```

How can I activate my plugin, what exactly do I need to change?

Answer (score 0):

dirname only accepts one parameter, you're passing two. i.e needs to be `dirname(__FILE__)`